# How to configure Ejabberd server:supportsInBandRegistration=True?

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd

i wish to register new user in Ejabberd with XMPPFramework, but supportsInBandRegistration is false, how to configure Ejabberd server:supportsInBandRegistration = true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `mod_register`. This is documented in ejabberd configuration section: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modregister

Comment: Mickaël Rémond,Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Install ejabberd, the default: supportsInBandRegistration = true, if you disable in-band registration, you need edit ejabberd.yml
(./ejabberd-15.10/conf/):

### In-band registration allows registration of any possible username.

## To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.
  register:
    all: allow